# How do I get the shortest repitition of something in an array?

Tags: python, list

Let's say you have a list which only has two types of values and goes something like `['t','r','r','r','t','t','r','r','t']` and you want to find the length of the smallest sequence number of `'r'`s which have `'t'`s at both ends.

In this case the smallest sequence of `'r'` has a **length of 2**, because there is first `t,r,r,r,t` and then `t,r,r,t,` and the latter has the smallest number of `'r'`s in a row surrounded by `'t'` and the number of `'r'`s is 2.

How would I code for finding that number?

This is from a problem of trying of going to a play with your friend, and you want to sit as close as possible with your friend, so you are trying to find the smallest amount of taken seats in between two free seats at a play. "#" is a taken seat and a "." is a free seat. you are given the amount of seats, and the seating arrangement (free seats and taken seats), and they are all in one line.
An example of an input is:

```
5
#.##.
```

where there are two taken seats(##) in between two free seats.

Here is my code which is not working for inputs that I don't know, but working for inputs I throw at it.

```
import sys

seats = int(input())
configuration = input()
seatsArray = []
betweenSeats = 1
betweenSeatsMin = 1
checked = 0
theArray = []
dotCount = 0
for i in configuration:
  seatsArray.append(i)

for i in range(len(seatsArray)):
  if i == len(seatsArray) - 1:
    break
  if seatsArray[i] == "." and seatsArray[i+1] == ".":
    print(0)
    sys.exit()

for i in range(0,len(seatsArray)):
  if i > 0:
    if checked == seats:
      break
  checked += 1
  if seatsArray[i] == "#":
    if i > 0:
      if seatsArray[i-1] == "#":
        betweenSeats += 1

  if seatsArray[i] == ".":
    dotCount += 1
    if dotCount > 1:
      theArray.append(betweenSeats)
    betweenSeats = 1

theArray = sorted(theArray)
if theArray.count(1) > 0:
  theArray.remove(1)
theArray = list(dict.fromkeys(theArray))

print(theArray[0])
```

Comment: This platform is not for asking other people to do your code for you - try it yourself, and then ask this question again! (Believe me, it's more fun to try it and succeeding yourself)

Comment: Can ending t for one r seq be the starting t for another r seq ?

Comment: @megargayu i have tried it, what i have done is that i have added the number of 'r' in every 'r' sequence to an array, and then sorted that list and picked the first index, meaning i should get the smallest answer, yet it's not working. So im looking for better logic in solving this problem.

Comment: @AajKaal yes it can

Comment: @InsertaRandomNameNow Could you post your code? Once you do that, I'll be happy to help you. (This seems like a really interesting problem) Check out [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Result should be **0**, due to the `'t','t'`.

Comment: @megargayu my code is actually for a "coding puzzle" and tbh the code is working for every type of input im putting it at, yet when i try to submit my code, im getting the length of the smallest sequence wrong, but i don't have access to the inputs. should i still post my code its kinda messy?

Comment: @superbrain it shouldnt be 0 because i only want the length of 'r' sequence, not 't' sequence.

Comment: Please add the link to the puzzle.

Comment: @InsertaRandomNameNow if you post the current code you are using, we can help you find what mistakes you are making. The reason I don't want to help you right now and "give you the code" is because this platform is not for homework help, and it's better to learn from your mistakes.

Comment: There's a 0-length sequence of 'r' between the two 't'.

Comment: @superbrain I think what they mean is that he wants at least one 'r' in between the two 't's

Comment: @megargayu I don't think so. I think what "he" wants is to solve the puzzle, so it matters what *the puzzle* wants. And as far as I can tell, it wants 0.

Comment: @superbrain Oh, I see. That seems like a possible explanation why the grader is giving OP a fail.

Comment: @megargayu Maybe, maybe not, yes. If they had linked the problem or quoted it or given us their code, we could do something, but of course they chose to not do any of that...

Comment: @megargayu wait i dont understand what you mean by i want atleast one "r" between the two "t"s.

Comment: ok ive posted my code pls look through it

Comment: @megargayu With the story now added, I guess my guess was correct. Certainly you don't want to sit as close as possible to your friend but with at least one stranger in between.

Comment: @superbrain no, if there is a seating arrangement of #..##, then you want to sit in those two dots which are close to each other, giving a value of 0.

Comment: @InsertaRandomNameNow Exactly. So why do you say that the result for your example should be 2, instead of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Create a string from list and then search for pattern required and then count r in the found matches and then take  min of it
Code:

```
import re
lst = ['t','r','r','r','t','t','r','r','t']
text = ''.join(lst)
pattern = '(?<=t)r+(?=t)'
smallest_r_seq = min(match.group().count('r') for match in re.finditer(pattern, text))
print(smallest_r_seq)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: Again, no explanation

Comment: Also, please don't give OP their homework! Let them try it, and THEN BUILD ON TOP OF THEIR CODE!

Comment: added pattern -- cut and paste issue sorry

Comment: I mean, while @megargayu is right, that OP should have shown his effort, this is almost exactly what I would have done and I think it's a readable and reasonably fast approach, so this is still a +1 from me. Also, OP has shown his efforts now, so I think it's fair to show other solutions

Comment: in this case -- not possible to built on the top of the code since it is not pythonic

Comment: @superbrain I allowed myself to correct the pattern; this should work now. Sorry, that I didn't see the obvious problem before :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a noob and a !optimal approach to your problem using a counter for the minimum and maximum sequence where ew compare both and return the minimum.

```
''' create a funciton that
    will find min sequence
    of target char
    in a list'''
    
def finder(a, target):
    max_counter = 0
    min_counter = 0

    ''' iterate through our list
    and if the element is the target
    increase our max counter by 1 
    '''
    for i in x:
        if i == target:
            max_counter += 1
            
            '''min here is 0
            so it will always be less
            so we overwrite it's value
            with the value of max_counter'''
            if min_counter < max_counter:
                min_counter = max_counter

            '''at last iteration max counter will be less than min counter
            so we overwrite it'''
            if max_counter < min_counter:
                min_counter = max_counter
    
        else:

            max_counter = 0
    return min_counter


x = ['t','r','r','r','t','t','r','r','t','t','t','r','t'] 
y = 'r'
print(finder(x,y))
```